# how to show image on page from mongodb in node js and handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

i am new in node js, and I am trying to  fetch an image  using node js and mongo DB. I m facing problem to get data from mongodb on html page.

Answer (score 0):

for getting data from MongoDB you need to create a connection between your node Apps and Mongo service instance. after that you are able to get data from MongoDB and
and show on your HTML.
for more details you can refer [building-a-simple-web-application-with-node](https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-simple-web-application-with-node-express-mongodb-dcd53231e83c)